# Scrapy - Manual Login

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, manual

I am building a very simple scraper using scrapy in order to scrape a certain element from a set of urls. However, I have to be logged in to the website in order to do this and I can not get the login part of my scraper working.

Is it possible to login to the website manually and then let my scraper do the scraping task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the [documentation related to performing login](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin)?

Comment: Yes of course I have. However, I think the FormRequest class does not handle all the hidden input fields well. And since the rest of the scraping is pretty straight forward, and only has to be performed once, a manual login seems the most efficient way.

Comment: _However, I think the FormRequest class does not handle all the hidden input fields well._ why do you think so? do you have sample input and test code showing the problem? It's hard to help you without evidence of something not working as you expect. The docs say it's possible (and I have used it myself sometimes) so there must be something special or non-obvious about your use-case.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I am asking if it is possible to do a manual login and then use my scrapy scraper. I am not asking to login using scrapy

Comment: Ah, ok. well I don't know what you mean by "manual login" then.

Comment: Alright, a manual login as in: I login by typing the desired username and pass word and then clicking the login button myself. And then use the authenticated session with scrapy.

I understand you would like to help me using scrapy to login, but I can figure that out myself. I just want to know if I can bypass this because that would be faster

Comment: If you mean passing `Cookie` headers, you can add those in your requests as `headers` dict. You probably want to [disable `CookiesMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?#std:setting-COOKIES_ENABLED)

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you.

Comment: Please try not to comment on a question with an already accepted answer. Rafael Almeida provided me exactly with the answer i needed, so my question was clear enough.

There was no attempt needed, I just needed to know if a manual login was possible in scrapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you're asking but you just can't "Manually login" using scrapy, you have to inject cookies onto it.

The best way I see to do this is by using Selenium to login and let it create cookies to feed scrapy here's how:

```
def get_cookies(self):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    base_url = "http://www.example.com/login"
    driver.get(base_url)
    #Code to login
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("my_username")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("my_password")
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
    #get the cookies created
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    driver.close()
    return cookies

def parse(self, response):
    return Request(url="http://my_domain.com/",
    cookies=self.get_cookies(),
    callback=self.login)

def login(self, response):
    #You'll have the cookies here
```

The code may require some tweaking here and there but this is the general idea

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. 
Eventually I managed to get the login to work using FormRequest.from_response(). I did not need to do anything with cookies.
However, for my use case a manual login would have been more efficient because I only have to run the scraper once.